# Delete something from sql

Tags: php, sql

I want to delete columns in my sql, which is going with succes. But there is another problem, I need to solve. I've tried and checked here around. All with any kind of succes I will try to explain my problem.

I've a member system where you can add your content, edit you submitted content and now I'm creating to delete your content. My script can delete now post which are created by the same user as logged in. For example my account is called `Bobby` and someone is called `Alex` I cannot delete the content of `Alex` only mimes, thats what I want.

For example my content link of `bobby` : `category.php?nameID=cat2&id=22` And the delete link is `deletepost.php?id=22`

EX. content link `Alex`:

`category.php?nameID=cat2&id=23` And the delete link is `deletepost.php?id=23` 
When I'm logged in as `Bobby` and I go to `deletepost.php?id=23` and receive a message like `You cannot delete this content!`

And When I go to mimes `deletepost.php?id=22` I need to receive a message like: `Your content has been delete succesfully!`

I'm only receive `NO!`

```
<?php
$user = new User();
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
    }

    if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
        $pakuser = $user->data()->username;
        $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM post 
            WHERE post.id = '$id' AND post.add = '$pakuser'")
            or die(mysql_error());
        if (!$sql) {
            echo 'NO';
        }
        if ($sql) {
            echo 'YES';
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: DO NOT use GET method for delete.  Either use POST or use GET that sends to a confirmation page that is then POST.

Comment: Your code is prone to sql injections. Further, you should definitely stop using the mysql connector and instead use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Everything is working fine, only I don't get the Succes message and fail message

Comment: @AbraCadaver, better yet, use [`DELETE`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside from the possible sql injections in your code, you can try this format for a delete query to determine the mistake:

```
<?php
$sql = " 
    DELETE FROM 
        post  
    WHERE 
        post.id = ".$id." AND post.add = '".$pakuser."'
";

if(!$res = mysql_query($sql)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql); 
} 
elseif(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) 
{ 
    echo 'No records Deleted. <br />Query: '.$sql; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'There are '.mysql_affected_rows().' records deleted.'; 
}
?>
```

Are you also sure that post.add is the username?